# Postgres - Create user with readonly access to VIEW and not the underlying TABLE

Tags: postgresql

On a postgres database, I have a database payloads under which I have a schema payloads and a table system_event within that schema. I have created a view on table system_event and named it rv_system_event.

I would like to create a user view_reader such that this user can only query the view rv_system_event and cannot read/write to table system_event.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I was able to find a solution. Sharing the knowledge here.

-- Connect as user postgres, connect to DB payloads

```
CREATE USER view_reader WITH PASSWORD 'view_reader';
ALTER ROLE view_reader SET search_path TO payloads;
```

-- Connect as user payloads_owner to DB payloads

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW payloads.rv_system_event AS SELECT id, event_id, event_type_id, tenant, intg_type, event_type, trigger_type, created_at, updated_at, status, prc_api FROM payloads.system_event;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA payloads TO view_reader;

GRANT SELECT ON rv_system_event TO view_reader;
```

-- Connect as user view_reader

```
SELECT * FROM system_event;
[Error: permission denied for table system_event]

SELECT * FROM rv_system_event;
[View results]
```